# Need the last non-NULL row of a data set in mysql grouped by a 2nd field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not too good at (my)SQL so here's a table and a question. I use the table to hold a history. I'd like to return the complete row that was most recent(*) and has a non-NULL value for `field1`. If there isn't such a row, I'd like to get any of the row where `field1` was NULL.

*) Recent meaning, it has the highest `id` (the 'a'-'s below).

Table and example:

```
| id | field1 | field2 |
------------------------
|  1 | (null) |     34 | <--b 
|  2 |     77 |   1234 |
|  3 | (null) |   1234 |
|  4 | (null) |    234 |
|  5 | (null) |     34 | <--b
|  6 |     99 |   1234 |
|  7 |     42 |   1234 | <--a
|  8 |     13 |    234 | <--a
|  9 | (null) |    234 |
```

I'd like to get three rows, as there are three distinct `field2` values. I'd like the rows marked with an 'a' as they are most recent and have a non-NULL `field1`. And I'd like to have one of the two 'b'-'s (doesn't matter which one for me). Making three total.

I tried a statement like:

```
SELECT MAX(id), field1, field2
FROM table1
GROUP BY field2;
```

But that does not yield the desired result.

Comment: why are they `a` or `b`?

Comment: There are 3 different requests in your question which are contrary to each other. Not clear at all...

Comment: I clarified my question and explained the 'a' and 'b' and added an attempt as an example. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT field2
          FROM table1
        ) AS dt
    JOIN
        table1 AS t
            ON t.id = COALESCE(
                ( SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
                  FROM table1
                  WHERE field2 = dt.field2
                    AND field1 IS NOT NULL 
                ),
                ( SELECT MAX(id)
                  FROM table1
                  WHERE field2 = dt.field2
                ) 
                              ) ;
```

Another way:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT field2
          FROM table1
        ) AS dt
    JOIN
        table1 AS t
            ON t.id = 
               ( SELECT id
                 FROM table1
                 WHERE field2 = dt.field2
                 ORDER BY (field1 IS NULL)
                        , id DESC
                   LIMIT 1
               ) ;
```

Tested in (your) **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/298cf/16)**

Comment: As part of improving my question i discovered this site where i ran your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/298cf/2 . It seems to be working quite fine! I'll test it out at home later tonight + i need to readup what `COALESCE` does :).

Comment: Thanks, both work. Which is the one you think i should be using? The join i reckon, it only has one embedded select extra? (btw, COALESCE is a handy function) Thanks again for the help.